# How to remove the implicit "self" argument on autocompletion in jedi-vim

Tags: vim, python-jedi

I just installed jedi-vim. When Jedi autocompletes a method, the first argument is always `self`, that is implicit in the method call.

How can I get rid of `self`?

[image: autocomplete an object]

Comment: Becoming a Buddhist should help. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Jedi bug. It used to work once - and still does for normal classes:

```
str.center(  # Yields self, width, fieldchar=None
str().center(  # Yields width, fieldchar=None
```

However it doesn't seem to work for literals. So please either report it here:
https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/ or fix the bug yourself and make a pull request on github.